# Create new UIImage each time or once

Tags: swift, ios

I am writing a control that has a toggle on (show/hide password). The `UITextfield` has a `UIImageView` in that acts as the toggle.

The question is, is it better to create the state images once and store them in the control, or to create them on demand?

Essentially this:

```
if let imageView = imgToggle {
    if self.isSecureTextEntry {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "eye.png")
    } else {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "no_eye.png")
    }
}
```

vs this:

```
private var showPassword: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "eye.png")
private var hidePassword: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "no_eye.png")

///...

if let imageView = imgToggle {
    if self.isSecureTextEntry {
        imageView.image = showPassword
    } else {
        imageView.image = hidePassword
    }
}
```

Is there any overhead in constantly recreating the image? How does that compare to storing the image in the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overhead in calling `UIImage(named: ...)` repeatedly,
because the UIKit framework already caches the image, as documented
in the [`UIImage(named:)` reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init):

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns the variant of that image that is best suited for the main screen. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or from an available asset catalog, and then returns the resulting object.

So keep it simple and assign the image object where needed:

```
if self.isSecureTextEntry {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "eye.png")
} else {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "no_eye.png")
}
```

or shorter:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: isSecureTextEntry ? "eye.png" : "no_eye.png")
```

Note that `self` is not necessary to access instance members.

Or use *image literals,* a feature introduced in Xcode 8.
You can simply type the name of an image resource in the asset catalog. This will be autocompleted to `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "<name>")`, but *displayed* as the image itself

[image]

in the Xcode source editor.

This is useful to avoid typing errors in the image name, and to visually
check if the right image was chosen. You can even double-click on
the image icon and choose a different one.